# How to format the explain plan output in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-execution-plan

I believe, Question is self-explanatory. The explain plan out table in sqlplus, Looks collapsed. It is hard to interpret each line. I tried to set the linesize but it does not work. Can you able provide any suggestion to format the output?

Solution:
As I am using CMD. I just adjust the width of CMD and set line size to 132 in sqlplus. It worked as I expected.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
set linesize value_size
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I set the line size as you suggested and adjusted command prompt width then It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) can show a query plan in a nice graphical representation. For example:

[image]

Comment: Sql query have bind variablea. Is it possible to set the variable value and pass in sql statement in Oracle SQL developer?

Comment: @Thillakan Sure. Just use the normal `:parameter_name` syntax and SQL Developer will show a dialog allowing you to enter parameter value(s) before query execution.